# Running luigi pipeline with different parameters simultaneously

Tags: python, luigi

Maybe this is a bit of a dumb question. I wrote a data pipeline using luigi and python that takes some file, cleans it up, and runs a Monte Carlo Markov Chain model. I need to run this model quite a number of times (25 simulations with different parameters). One simulation takes about 3-5 hours to run on my laptop. Is there a way to either simultaneously run more than one simulation (i'm assuming this is subject to hardware limitations) or schedule a simulation to be run after the first is completed the problem with this is that the output files would have the same name, i'm assuming this means that every simulation run after the first one would be marked as complete until I delete these output files

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. You just need to have a root scheduling task as described here: https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/luigi_patterns.html#triggering-many-tasks

Basically, you just create one root task that has the 25 different sets of parameters and requires your workflow with those parameters.

Edit: If you need to run one task before another, simply use `yield Task(params)` in the `run` method (not the requires method!).